# Inline javascript codes don't work after next page via ajax loader

Tags: javascript, ajax, loader

I have a problem with ajax loader (wordpress)

I am using a theme and the theme's ajax loader button killing my inline script.

I read much more then 10 article about this issue but I cant get any solution.

how can we do about this question?

this is my javascript code.

```js
if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined') {
  document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML =
    'Browser not supported Storage...';
} else {
  
$('.item').each(function() {
    var div = $(this).closest(".item").attr("id");
    
    if (localStorage["Catalin-" + div] == 1) {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
    
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  
  
$('.buton').on('click', function() {   
   var div1 = $(this).closest(".item").attr("id");
   var $oku_kontrol = $(this).closest('.item');
   
   $oku_kontrol.toggleClass('selected');
   
   if ($oku_kontrol.hasClass('selected')) {
     localStorage.setItem("Catalin-" + div1, 1);
   }
   else {
     localStorage.setItem("Catalin-" + div1, 0);
   }
     
});   
  
  
});  
  
}
```

```css
.item {
    width:200px;
    height:80px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.selected {
background-color:yellow;
}

.buton:after {
color:white;
display:inline-block;
padding:6px;
background:green;
content:"Click Me!";
}

.selected .buton:after {
background:black;
content:"You already did ;)";
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="1" class="item">1<br>
<a class="buton"></a>
</div>

<div id="2" class="item">2<br>
<a class="buton"></a>
</div>

<div id="3" class="item">3<br>
<a class="buton"></a>
</div>


<div id="warning"></div>
```

this code working at whole website. but when the page loader(working with ajax) load some of content in the same div: there is no console error but the code not working anymore. so click function dont working too.

Many thanks.

this is my ajax loader javascript code

```js
  $('.pager_load_more').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   
   var el = $(this);
   var pager = el.closest('.pager_lm');
   var href = el.attr('href');
   
   // index | for many items on the page
   var index = $('.lm_wrapper').index(el.closest('.isotope_wrapper').find('.lm_wrapper'));

   el.fadeOut(50);
   pager.addClass('loading');
   
   $.get( href, function(data){

    // content
    var content = $('.lm_wrapper:eq('+ index +')', data).wrapInner('').html();

    if( $('.lm_wrapper:eq('+ index +')').hasClass('isotope') ){
     // isotope
     $('.lm_wrapper:eq('+ index +')').append( $(content) ).isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' });
    } else {
     // default
     $( content ).hide().appendTo('.lm_wrapper:eq('+ index +')').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    
    // next page link
    href = $( '.pager_load_more:eq('+ index +')', data ).attr('href');  
    pager.removeClass('loading');     
    if( href ){
     el.fadeIn();
     el.attr( 'href', href );
    }

    // refresh some staff -------------------------------

    mfn_greyscale();
    
    mfn_jPlayer();
    
    mfn_pretty();

    // isotope fix: second resize
    
    setTimeout(function(){
     $('.lm_wrapper.isotope').isotope( 'layout');
    },1000);
    
    
   });

  });
```

Comment: We would need to know how this ajax loader works. If it isn't properly extracting and then executing scripts at the right time, nothing you can do will fix this problem other than disabling it. Evidence seems to indicate it doesn't handle scripts properly.

Comment: thanks for your interest. this is my codepen example. can you check it for me? https://codepen.io/gecedergi/pen/OjyZyJ many thanks

Comment: Mehmet, you need to post your ajax request as well so we can see what is changing after ajax. With in this code you posted, it all works but, we can't really tell what manipulation ajax does to elements so click event handler disappears.

Comment: what about it? seems to work fine. but that working is unrelated to the ajax loader being built to handle scripts on the page.

Comment: hi again. i don't have any information about my themes ajax loader code or working principle. can you write clearly to what you wanna see? and i know this code working like you said. but in the website: when we click load more button; page loading some posts in same div area. no reload, no next page, just geting it in the same page. but the additional posts click me buttons doesnt working. if you want to check it via on my website: i can share my website link with you. many thanks

Comment: Feels like the page loader is changing the DOM so the jQuery binding is lost.  Try binding to an outer element (but please dont bind to then entire document).  Something like `$('#outerDiv').on('click', '.innerElement', function(){....}`

Comment: i did that but the permalink changes with "page/2/" and if i want to use like that why i have to use load more:]

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that the page loader is changing the DOM which is killing your jQuery bindings.  When dealing with dynamically loading content, you want to follow this format.

1. Wrap the stuff that dynamically loads inside of a container like a div.

   ```
   <div id="outerDiv">
       //... stuff that gets reloaded here
   </div>
   ```
2. Then for your jQuery binding, you bind to the outer container using this.

   ```
   $(document).load(function()
   {
       $('#outerDiv').on('click', '.button', function(e)
       {
           e.preventDefault();//------ add this
           e.stopPropagation();
           // whatever your button does

           return false;
       });
   });
   ```

Here is what is happening.  Say we just use this

```
    $('.buton').on('click', function().....
```

When the page loads, jQuery looks for every single `.buton` and attaches the `click` listener to it.  But then your page loader changes those items.  JQuery would have to go back and rebind everything in order to know what is on the page (but don't do that).  Instead. you bind to one item that *doesn't* change.  Since the `outerDiv` is still there, that is what jQuery finds.  Then it looks inside of it to find any `.button` items to use.

EDIT:  Your anchor tags are causing the navigation so interrupt them using `e.preventDefault()`.  You can add `e.stopPropagation()` as well but that shouldn't be the issue here.  Don't forget to put the `e` in `function(e)` just above it.

Comment: your solution working well and i got it. but the page was loading again and going to .../page/2/ and i don't want this. your advice doesn't work in the same page. can we do it about it. many thanks

Comment: i am talking about .preventDefault(); and if we remove that page going to page2 and this is not ok.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the `e.preventDefault()` is that not working for you?

Comment: Hello again. Your code don't working in the same page. going to second or etc. page. i already tried a solution before like you wrote. but it is not working too. when we add "$(document).load(function()" function to code: the page always going to second page. Like: "example.com/page/2/"

Comment: I don't see anything else in the code that could be responsible for this.  You could try adding `return false;` at the end of the binding function.  That shouldn't make a difference but it is worth a shot.

Comment: ok we can try once again :] can you edit your code with "return false;" please. many thanks

Comment: I added this code to in my ajax loader click function.

`$.getScript("example.js");`

And i copied my inline script with different var tags in that example script and the problem resolved.